# Is volume taken by hidden orders visible to all traders?

Tags: stocks, trading, stock-exchanges

Institutions can place orders that are hidden from Level 2 book. Do these order remain "hidden" after they execute?

Imagine `AAPL` bid and ask are $157.90 and $157.92, and, there is a hidden order for 10M shares to sell at $157.91. Then it's matched by another hidden order to buy 10M shares at $157.91, that is these hidden orders didn't affect all regular orders on L2 book. Will regular/retail traders see the 10M shares in the volume bar, or we won't even know that huge amount of shares changed hands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cross trade is when a broker receives a buy and sell orders at the same price for the same security.  There are some rules and limitations but assuming all conditions are met (price is competitive, etc.), the broker executes the trade  between his two customers. These  orders are not listed publicly and they are not reported.

A hidden order is not displayed to the public in the  electronic order book.  Or perhaps it could be an Iceberg order where  only the  ‘tip’ is shown. Because these orders have been submitted to an exchange, executed volume is reported on the exchange.